# Раздельное написание "без умолку"

Tags: слитно-раздельно, наречия, егэ

Предложение:

> ...воробьи без(?)умолку "беседовали" о чем-то между собой.

"Без умолку", в данном случае, является наречием. Почему его принято писать раздельно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Наречные выражения с предлогами БЕЗ и ДО пишутся раздельно даже в том случае, если слово не употребляется без предлога.**

Для данной группы слов **падежное управление**  (и фактически предметное значение, можно задать падежный вопрос без чего?) имеет преимущественное значение, поэтому они пишутся раздельно: ***до зарезу, до упаду, без умолку, без прОсыпа, без ведома, без продыху***.

В том числе **согласно фонетическому принципу** (предлог на согласную, а наречие на гласную): ***без умолку, без устали, без удержу,  без обиняков, без оглядки*** – раздельное написание предлога БЕЗ.

Наречия с предлогом ДО, отнесенные к этой теме,  пишутся слитно только в трех исключительных случаях: ***дотла, дотоле, доселе***.

Answer (score 1):

Это употребленное в наречном значении сочетание существительного с предлогом.

См. у Розенталя [§ 54. Раздельное написание наречных выражений](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=164)